# TCPDF return to previous page after print dialog close

Tags: javascript, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to generate documents for an online application. 
I want the user to return to the form after print because the user will capture data again.

I have tried opening the pdf in a new tab / window and calling `window.close()` after print,  but to use `window.close()` the form must open using `window.open()` which is not the case. Form action opens the window.

I have then tried to open the form in the same tab and calling `history.back()`, but also not working (by not working I refer to the page remains on the pdf.

Code I have tried (amongst many other)

```
$js = <<<EOD
window.print();
document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
EOD;
```

and

```
$js = <<<EOD
window.print();
 window.history.back();
EOD;
```

and

```
$js = <<<EOD
window.print();
 history.go(-1);
EOD;
```

and

```
$js = <<<EOD
window.print();
window.addEventListener("afterprint", "window.history.back();");
EOD;
```

This code works when not in TCPDF:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
window.print();
window.onafterprint = function(){
window.history.go(-1);
}
});
</script>
```

This must work in TCPDF

Any suggestions?

Comment: use an Iframe ?

Comment: @Vidal thanks for the advise. I tried and it almost worked. Part of the data capture form is taking a photo. I then encode the image using base64 to send to the pdf page where it is decoded. The URL becomes to long when the base4 encode string is included.

Comment: you can use ajax to send the image via post also with the form values, then with javascript create the iframe and display the pdf.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you load a PDF file directly, then that page does not have JS running on it, so you can not close it with JS

The best solution I can suggest is to use [ViewerJS](https://viewerjs.org/), which a PDF reader written in JS, so you can still run code at the same time as displaying the document.