# URL Too Long when posting base64 encode image using $_GET

Tags: php, get, base64, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to create a once off document of data captured by users.

I need the page to returned back to the data capture page agter print.

As I explained in [TCPDF return to previous page after print dialog close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59186544/tcpdf-return-to-previous-page-after-print-dialog-close?noredirect=1#comment104813901_59186544) window.history.back() and window.history.go(-1); does not work in TCPDF (not returning to previous page after print).

Vidal suggested that I use an Iframe. I did and it worked perfect, using `$_GET[]` to obtain variables, until I sent base64 encoded value of an image.

I got an error: `URI Too Long`.

The base64 value is thousands of characters long and the `$_GET[]` wont take it. If I use `$_POST[]` and send the variable to TCPDF it works but then I have the issue as per first question.

I know that sending the values to a database and generate the PDF from the database values will work, but storing the values in a database is not an option due to privacy issues. The PDF will contain private information and the owner receives the only copy.

Here is my code for the iframe:

```
<?php echo "<iframe src='TCPDF/profiles/profile.php?Name=$name&Surname=$surname&age=$age&othervariables=$othervariables&imgstring=$encodedPhoto' style='position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;'>
Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>   "?>
```

In TCPDF:

```
$name = $_POST['childName'];
$surname = $_GET['childSurname'];
$age = $_GET['age'];
$encodedPhoto = $_GET['imgstring'];
```

This is sample code , alot more variables are going through. 11 Images must be encoded and send to pdf.

I have read that `$file_get_contents();` but I cannot figure out how it will be done without uploading it the a server  because you need to include a `path/to/file`.

Is there a way to send the data to the iframe page using `$_POST` or any other way?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to be answerable. Don't you have any security concerns? URL's are stored in the browser's history, so putting private information in an URL is a bad idea.

Comment: @KIKO Software thanks for the advise on security. In short. My question is how do I get variables from the parent page the the iframe, including an image which I converted to base64.

Comment: I don't think the information needs to flow from the parent page to the inline frame. Both are generated by the server, and the information should exist on the server, so it would make sense to send the information directly from the server to both the parent page and the inline frame.

Comment: As mentioned, I so not store the information on the server. It is generates by a data capture page

Comment: I understand. However, both pages are generated by PHP, so it would make sense to store the data on the server. You could store it in a [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php). That is an easy way to share data between PHP scripts for an unique user. Be aware of [session hijacking](http://shiflett.org/articles/session-hijacking) when you use this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If you post an answer I will upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use sessions

I see that both pages, the parent and the iframe, are generated using PHP. In that case you would not want to send too much data, from one script to the other, via `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

You would normally use [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) to share data between scripts. In the parent page you store the data in the `$_SESSION` array and in the iframe you retrieve it.

Be aware of [session hijacking](http://shiflett.org/articles/session-hijacking) when you use this.

Comment: If I clear the session variables after print (for the next data to be captured) will it clear the session id as well? I dont want the user to log in after each capture.

Comment: No, a session ID is not cleared when you `unset()` certain session variables. An user doesn't need to log in to get a session. You can even keep a session alive between visits. The best thing to do is to read up on PHP sessions, play with them, and learn that way how they exactly work.